# How to fade the bottom edge of a rendered component until a re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a reviews microservice for an e-commerce site using react and react-bootstrap, and display 5 reviews before a button to expand the reviews shown. I want, at the bottom of my list of review components within my reviewList component, the edge to be faded until I click the button to display more reviews.

I have an example from Etsy of exactly the way that I would like for it to look.

I've tried a some css and react-bootstrap, but I need only the bottom of the entire reviewList component of reviews components to have the fade.

Here's the example:
[image: Example of faded edge of reviews]

You can see the bottom of the last review is faded.

I expect to have the bottom in a state of fade until the expand button is clicked but can only find ways to animate or fade each review component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style the container component so that the bottom edge of the container has a pseudo-element with a transparent to semi-transparent to opaque background. This can be achieved by creating a pseudo-element for the container and setting it's background-image to have a linear-gradient with the opacity coming from rgba colours (the a in rgba is the transparency).

Alternatively, you could make the transparent to opaque background in photoshop and set that as the background image.

```
<div className="review-list-container">
    <ReviewList />
</div>

.review-list-container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); / 
  /*alternatively, create desired gradient effect as a png in photoshop */
}
```

see here - https://codepen.io/Roughton/pen/dBxmdw

Comment: Worked beautifully for me, https://www.mountsinaicharcot.org/search